# 'Named' slave the same as having forwarders?

Tags: bind

I have a slave DNS server that dumped a bunch of...

```
" error (unexpected RCODE REFUSED) resolving 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.in-addr.arpa/PTR/IN'"
```

messages all the sudden, and DNS lookups to the slave server did not respond.

From what I can tell this is generally due to having forwarders in the configuration file that refused to respond.

However I do not have any forwarders in my configuration file, but it is configured as a slave DNS server for my zone.

The odd thing is, a restart of the slave DNS server fixed the issue and I no longer got those errors, no action was taken on the upstream master.

Any thoughts on what may have caused this?